# Store Filter in Custom Collection and Conditionally Execute

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have Cusom collection object containing a collection of objects.  I then have two UI elements (a grid and chart) bound to this single object.  The grid shows all the objects and the chart shows a subset of the same collection.

What I want to be able to do is register a filter in the collection (Func<>?) and conditionally execute the filter to create the subset collection.

Really not sure how to approach this.  Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Is it that you want a set of predefined filters someone can choose from without knowing the specifics of the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in the Func<> into the Where() static method. The output will be a new IEnumerable collection you can bind to your UI elements. The function you register must be of type `Func<ItemInYourCollection, Boolean>`.

If you want to switch between using the filter and not using the filter, it may be easiest to use a "non-filtering" function:

```
Func<ItemInYourCollection, Boolean> filter = (a) => true;
if(filtering) filter = registeredFilter;
UI.Data = rawData.Where(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) extension method or [syntax-based query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) to indicate which elements should be placed in that chart. It would be possible only if your collection implements IEnumarable interface.

An example of Where extension method could be something like that:

```
var filteredItem = items.Where(i => i.type == typeYouLookFor)
```

It uses [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) so you don't have to declare any additional function.